# psd to html dimensions

Tags: html, css, psd

I am starting learning html 5 and css3 and recently i tried to convert one of my designs in Photoshop to html  and modify with CSS.

Everything went well except of dimension on the full screen. My psd file has dimension of 1020px x 1834px . Now when I put it on full screen on my 27" screen it has a lot of space between the edges [psd design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuGx0.jpg)

[htm/css design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5pGA.jpg)

Is there any specific command for different screens or monitoring. I have also used
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
and putted on my body in css the dimensions of psd 
Any ideas?

Comment: What's supposed to happen? How does your code look? Please refrain from image-only questions since we cannot check what's wrong.

Comment: I am new on forum is there any way to put the code on the initial post?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your design a little in your psd. A regular container on many websites has a width of 1440 pixels. Since your design is only 1020px wide, it's looking narrow when converted to HTML. Looking at your PSD design, I suggest let your original psd be at least 1640px wide, leaving a gap of 100px on each side.

Comment: Sorry if I am getting it wrong but let's say that I overstretch the images or crop them on a higher ratio. How can I make the m fit the edge of the screen since it seems whatever I put in the width: in css it remains in the borders of the body (1020px). I lalso tried to enlarge the body but did not work. Is there any way to send you the code?

Comment: from sky here is a dropbox link with my html and css https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ic8nhfybbrelrvk/AAARO0uye_2NlsMUUZTiMLhja?dl=0